# Parsing a text file - any reason why space / new line would be ignored?

Tags: c

I have this while loop...

```
char count[3] = {0};
int i = 0;

while( c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t' ) {
    count[i] = c;
    c = fgetc(fp);
    i++;    
}
```

And even though I see while debugging that space and newline are the right ASCII numbers, the while loop does not exit.  Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: `c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t'` is always true, regardless of `c`.

Comment: gah!  I need to step away from my pc.  You're right.  I should have done AND.  Thank you

Comment: Your first trip through the loop `c` is uninitialized and you must protect against writing beyond the end of `count`. Use `while (i < 3 && (c = fgetc(fp)) != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t')`

Comment: Suppose the character is a space. Then `c != ' '` is false, and `c != '\n'` is true, and `c != '\t'` is true, and `false || true || true` is true, so the loop keeps going.

Comment: Thanks guys for the tips!   Yeah, I get it now.  It just wasn't clicking before so I should have stepped away for a moment and think about it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic in the conditional is not right. It will evaluate to `true` all the time.

```
while( c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t' )
```

If `c` is equal to `' '` it is not equal to `'\n'` or `'\t'`.

What you probably need is:

```
while( c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' )
```

And for good measure, I would also add `c != EOF`.

```
while( c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t' && c != EOF )
```

It might be simpler to use:

```
while( !isspace(c) && c != EOF )
```

Comment: It might also be worthwhile to consider using [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) from `<ctype.h>`.

Comment: Got it thanks.  I realized it after the first comment - just didn't click before.

Comment: @cpd1, you are welcome. I bet you will see this error next time rather easily :) Happy programming.